# Select on Change will change another select html javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a select like this

```
<select  name="category" >

  <option value="0" selected>Select a Manufacturer</option>
    <option value="10">Acer Technologies</option>
  <option value="2">Alcatel</option>
  <option value="14">Apple Iphone</option>
  <option value="4">Azumi</option>
  <option value="12">HTC Corporation</option>
  <option value="8">Huawei</option>
  <option value="5">LG Electronics</option>
  <option value="11">Motorola</option>
  <option value="9">Nokia Microsoft</option>
  <option value="1">Samsung</option>
  <option value="6">Sony Ericsson</option>
  <option value="3">Zhong Xing ZTE</option>
</select>
```

And another select HIDDEN like this

```
<select  name="manufacturer" >

  <option value="none" selected>Select a Manufacturer</option>
    <option value="Acer Technologies">Acer Technologies</option>
  <option value="Alcatel">Alcatel</option>
  <option value="Apple Iphone">Apple Iphone</option>
  <option value="Azumi">Azumi</option>
  <option value="HTC Corporation">HTC Corporation</option>
  <option value="Huawei">Huawei</option>
  <option value="LG Electronics">LG Electronics</option>
  <option value="Motorola">Motorola</option>
  <option value="Nokia Microsoft">Nokia Microsoft</option>
  <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
  <option value="Sony Ericsson">Sony Ericsson</option>
  <option value="Zhong Xing ZTE">Zhong Xing ZTE</option>
</select>
```

Both selects are almost the same value, the first one is to save the manufacturer as category and the second one is to save the manufacturers name

The first one is visible while the second one is hidden ( display:none )

What I need is:

If the user select in select one for example

```
<option value="2">Alcatel</option>
```

In some way the hidden display:none select must be autoselected to

```
<option value="Alcatel">Alcatel</option>
```

Any way to do this?

I already have Jquery running other functions on the site

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `change` function:

```
$( "select[name='category']" ).change(function(e) {
     $( "select[name='manufacturer']" ).val( $(this).find( "option:selected" ).text() );
});
```

But if option text in `category` select do not match option value in `manufacturer` select - code will not work.

Comment: Worked just perfect thanks a lot I will mark the answer as correct in 3 minutes